# Why is a GPIO input floating when detecting output from an external source?

Tags: gpio

I am using a voltage divider built with two resistors (1K and 330 Ohms) so that I can reduce a 13V output from an external device (in this case a burglar alarm) down to a level acceptable to a Raspberry Pi GPIO input.

When connected up, the GPIO input floats, even though its internal pull-down resistor is activated. Based on a line in the burglar alarm manual, I think that both the power source of the Pi and the burglar alarm need to share a common negative, but I don't know how to achieve this.

This is the circuit at the moment:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not Pi specific.  Connect a Pi ground to the supply ground (marked 0V on your schematic).

Comment: Electric circuits are so called because you **NEED** a complete circuit for current to flow.